# In wpgeodirectory supreme theme how can I change the gear icon with a filter icon

Tags: wordpress

Actually the gear icon shows filters, and therefore I would like to replace it. I would like also not to spin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change icon

Goto
\plugins\geodir_advance_search_filters\geodirectory_advance_search_function.php    line 1774 and replace;

```
$default_btn_value = '<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

with

```
$default_btn_value = '<i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

2. Disable spinning of icon:

Goto plugins\geodir_advance_search_filters\js\frontend.js and comment line 1398:

```
jQuery('button.showFilters i').addClass('fa-spin');
```

change the respective line also frontend.min.js for immediate affect